# importing a flat file that contains both nulls and blanks

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS to import flat files into our database.  I have some control over the formatting of the files.  The source contains both nulls and blanks - and they need to be preserved.

I currently have the file pipe delimited with double-quotes to qualify text.  So this:

```
|"value a"|""||"value d"|
```

has "value a" in the first column, a blank in the second, null in the third, "valud d" in the fourth.

When I check the box **Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow**, blanks turn into NULL.  If I uncheck it, nulls turn to blanks.

How can I fix this in either SSIS or my modifying the spec of the flat file?

Comment: Can you double quote the output columns if you can control the flat file format?

Comment: I just realized I had a major typo in my question - I just fixed it.  I do use double quotes to qualify text.  Are you suggesting something different?

Comment: For your specific example, in the flat file configuration leave text qualifier as "none", and retain null value in the data source. Then you need to replace double quotation in next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Sucks, but what I would suggest is to use " " for empty string, with the setting to retain null values. Then, in a derived column or a script component transformation, if the value(s) are not null perform a trim on them, or explicitly check for a value of a single space and set it to an empty string.